# Snake hook in sculpt mode is creating glitch like shapes instead of smoth tentacles

Tags: sculpting, displacement, sculpt, distort

I don't have too much expirience in sculpting, but I have seen on videos i'ts seemingly easy to make smoth tentacles. But in my case what I get are ugly ditortions on ends. I tryed adding more verticies and using Multires modifier but it hardly helps. Is it just how snake hook works ?

[image]

[image]

Dytopo efects
[image]

Comment: The answer provided by @Gorgious is correct. Have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/sculpt_paint/sculpting/adaptive.html#dynamic-topology) for dynotopo, particularly detail size. The object should should be at least somewhat subdivided before using snake hook, smaller detail scale will also help.

Comment: Dyntopo and Multires are absolutely different workflows which shouldn't be used at the same time. Note after using dyntopo mesh is triangulated and can have bad shading. If using Dyntopo, there are Relative detail and Constant detail. Relative depends on the zoom level in viewport, Constant depends only on the number entered in its settings. However none of your screenshots show settings for dyntopo.

Comment: I subdivided the hell out of it @Timaroberts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable Dyntopo in the left panel, otherwise the tool will only displace geometry, until it gets horribly mangled and creates artifacts.

Dyntopo will generate new geometry on the fly, provided you don't move your mouse too fast it should create a smooth hook.

Don't forget to tweak the detail size if you think the generated geometry doesn't fit.

[image]

Also consider using the latest version if you can, there has been gigantic improvements since 2.79 in the sculpting area.

[Link to the official download page](https://www.blender.org/download/)

Comment: if that was this easy I would't ask here.  I already tryed to use dytopo and i have seen the effects on tutorials, but for me the dytopo somehow makes things worse. Instead of generating new geometry it somehow dicreases it, and it takes ages to enable it. The snake works the same in both 2.79 and 2.8, thats the biggest problem. See on the main question

Comment: Dear Rex, no need to get defensive, we are all learners here. Please read again the 3rd sentence of my answer. In short, click the arrow on the left of dyntopo and lower the detail size.